# Span and liner independence of a Set of Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

How to show vector spanning 
ie.   A=(u,v,w) B=(u+v,v+w,w+u)

Comment: What does (a) mean? Does it mean "if S *spans V*..." ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Note that 
$$\begin{align*}
u&=\frac{1}{2}[(u + v)-( v + w)+ (w + u)],\\
v&=\frac{1}{2}[(u + v)+( v + w)- (w + u)],\\
w&=\frac{1}{2}[-(u + v)+( v + w)+ (w + u)].
\end{align*}
$$
Hence any vector that is a linear combination of vectors of $S$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors of $T$.

b) If $a(u + v)+b(v + w)+c(w + u)=0$ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ then $(a+c)u+(a+b)v+(b+c)w=0$ and since  $S$ is linearly independent, it follows that $a+c=0$, $a+b=0$ and $b+c=0$.
Therefore $a=\frac{1}{2}[(a+c)+(a+b)-(b+c)]=0$. Similarly you get that $b=c=0$.

Comment: I posted my answer before seeing yours. Funny how our first hint is exactly the same :)

Comment: @benguin Yes, it is hard to imagine a different answer.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Hint: You can write $u = \frac{1}{2}((u+v)+(w+u)-(v+w))$.

(b) Hint: Try to prove the contrapositive, that if $T$ is linearly dependent, then $S$ is also. Start by assuming their is a non-trivial linear combination of vectors in $T$ that add to zero.